# Hard time creating a Microsoft Band tile icon

Tags: microsoft-band

It says in the Microsoft Band SDK Documentation about using a WriteableBitmap to create a tile icon, but how do I get it to point to the existing image I made for the Tile?

Comment: Can you be more specific, such as describing what you've tried, where the image exists (e.g. as an asset of the project?), how you're attempting to load it into memory and/or convert it to a Band icon?

Comment: The image exists as an asset of the project. I'm doing everything the Microsoft Band SDK Documentation is saying for creating a tile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your Windows Phone app has an asset named "Assets/Icon1.png", then that asset can be made into a BandIcon by something like:

```
using Microsoft.Band;
using Microsoft.Band.Tiles;
using Microsoft.Band.Tiles.Pages;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```

...

```
StorageFile imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icon1.png"));
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)
{
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1,1);
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
    return bitmap.ToBandIcon();
}
```

Comment: What do I set SmallIcon and TileIcon to? Also i'm omitting return.

Comment: A Tile can have up to 10 BandIcons: 1 TileIcon, 1 SmallIcon, and 8 additional icons. The TileIcon is displayed on the Band when the tile is not in the "badged" state. The SmallIcon is displayed on the Band when the tile is in the badged state (i.e. a number is displayed with the icon to show a message count or somesuch). The additional icons are for use in a custom layout (if your tile has a custom layout. If no SmallIcon is provided, then the TileIcon will be clipped and used when the tile is in the badged state.